# Creating a Facebook App

Tags: facebook

I am building a website for a client. He has a Facebook page for his business. On the homepage of his site, he wants a feed that will pull in all the updates from his business' Facebook page.

Now, I felt this would be very easy to implement (maybe it is) but I have scoured the Facebook API for any simple way to do this. I am having a lot of trouble understanding which way I should do this. I've settled on using JS to access it, but have no idea where to go from there.

Do I need to create an app? If so, which options do I select so I can access the clients facebook page?

How do I get my app that I've created to show up so a user can authorize it? I have so many questions, and Facebook isn't very good at giving me answers.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you just use the facebook page's RSS feed.

**Example**

Take his page URL e.g.

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Lazery-Attack/6001014870

Take the number at the end of the url off, and plug it into the facebook feeds URL e.g.

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=6001014870

Voila, you now have an RSS feed you can integrate into the website you are building.

**URL Breakdown**

The URL is broken down the following way:

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format={feedFormat}&id={PageID}

Vaid feed formats are:

1. RSS - rss20
2. Atom - atom10
3. JSON - json

**Other Examples**

*Atom*

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=6001014870

*JSON*

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=6001014870

Comment: I was hoping not to have to use XML. Prefer to use JSON. There must be a way to use the API to get that information?

Comment: Simple https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=6001014870.  I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: This all looks great, but how do I access the pageID? It is not on the end of the url, so I have no idea how to access it.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Use: https://graph.facebook.com/nameofthepage to get info on the page, including the page id. Thanks!

Comment: Doh, kind of assumed you would have access to the page itself (If it's your page it should show the ID in the URL).  The above works though, or you could examine the html markup of the like button, that has a attribute called "data-profileid" which holds the page ID as well.

Comment: Now, I've messed around with getting this URL into either PHP or JS with no luck. When I use PHP the object that gets returned is a Facebook page, saying that I am using a browser they don't support. Any idea how I can spoof Facebook into thinking I am using a browser? I used file_get_contents to grab it.

Comment: To be honest I've not looked at PHP for a very long time, a quick google brought up this way of setting your user agent which should get around the problems: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-change-user-agent-string/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the facebook API, right here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

You can give it a try here:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552%2Fposts

The like box: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ also has the latest posts available

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add a Like Button to the page and make sure "show Stream" is checked on as this will show all recent posts. You can customise the appearance also (e.g. width, height etc).

No App or messy API calls needed!

Try it out here and simply paste the resulting code into your webpage:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Answer (score 0):

Not an app, but the Facebook Social Plugins over here at [Facebook For Pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)

Comment: I should probably revise my question, but I need the page posts to be returned in some form of data that I can manipulate. Because the 'feed ' I will be making will also incorporate twitter and blog posts into a 'super feed.' So I would need the page posts in some form of object or array. I don't think the social plugins offer this much customizing, do they?

Comment: @jasonaburton They offer some customisation of the appearance as I mentioned in my answer (this link is the same as in mine, so if you click on it you can try out the customisations), but no they don't allow you to manipulate the content of the posts. I'd advise you to edit your question to specify that you need to do this to ensure you get suitable answers.